# Upload logo on link click

Tags: php, image, upload, image-uploading

I'm new to the concept of file uploading using a form in PHP. I would like to know a PHP script for the purpose of uploading a logo image onto a site. I tried couple of sample demos available on the web but I didn't get the image into my folder.

PS: I didn't understand many of the scripts given.

I would like to upload a logo image to replace my existing logo. How to do that?

I have a link 'Change Logo' on clicking which it should go to another page where I can use a file uploading form. {I would prefer if the form didn't have an action.} But where will the saved image be posted. I would like a customized script that would upload an image into my folder 'style/images/' as 'logo.png'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link, it will show a step by step procedure of file upload through the clear comments in the script itself. Hope this helps

http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/

Step 1 - Copy paste the above script and save it in a folder

Step 2 - Create a folder with name images in the same folder where the .php file with the above script pasted.

Step 3 - Upload a file sizes not greater than 100kb. The output should be File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!

Step 4 - To check whether the file is uploaded, check the images folder, you will find the uploaded file in the folder.

OR Try this

```
 <?
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    // echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    // echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    // echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    // echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
     $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="validate[required] text-input" />

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Attach file"  >
</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="filename"  value="<?echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];?>"/>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting 'Copy unsuccessful' as the output. I didn't understand why but I'm getting an error.

Comment: @ShyamK make sure the images folder is in the same directory of your php file which contains the above script. If you want the images folder to be in different path, Please change the path as per its location this is the place where you define the path for the images folder where your uploaded images will be stored $newname="images/".$image_name;

Comment: @ShyamK And also check the size of the uploaded image, as per the script you can only upload images sizes upto 100kb. If you want to upload bigger images change define ("MAX_SIZE","100") as per your need

Comment: The images folder is in the same folder as the php file containing the script. Also the file size of the uploaded image is only 7.8kb. What else might be the problem?

Comment: I increased the MAX_SIZE","100" to MAX_SIZE","10000" and I still got the same error.

Comment: @ShyamK I just tried the code even though i have tried it before. I had just updated my answer, I just mentioned step by step what I did to make the script work. Hope it helps

Comment: The error maybe in $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname); as the if statement is getting a false result from it. the if statement at the site that you mentioned checks for if(!copied) and then comes the echo message for the 'Copy unsuccessfull!'

Comment: @ShyamK Nice that you understood the working of the code, but it shows if the image is not copied (i.e uploaded). Then echo the error message. The main condition given is the path is not correct then show the error message

Comment: I did exactly what you said but I still get the same result.

I have my script in a file called 'index.php' in a folder 'Testing' and the folder 'images' is also inside the same folder, 'Testing'

I tried uploading a file 'logo.jpg' of size 7.8 kb but got 'Copy unsuccessfull!' as the output.

The folder 'images' doesn't contain anything. After running the script it still doesn't.

Comment: Tried the code. It shows 'Image Uploaded Successfully!' but no picture is displayed and also no image appears in the images folder. :(

Comment: @ShyamK Just clear your index.php in the testing folder and replace the above script. It will work for sure. It can upload any files as its common for all. Just wrote it to fix this problem completely. Make sure the images folder is in your testing folder.This will help you saving the image name in the database too, good luck :)

Comment: Failed...again.  I'm not using a database. I just want the uploaded pic to appear in my 'images' folder.

Comment: @ShyamK the above code works just fine for me, you don't need a database to execute the code. You just need the images folder and the script file in a same folder, nothing else. I tried my level best to give you the best answer.

Comment: It echoes 'Stored in: images/logo.jpg' but its not saving the file into the folder. I checked for hidden files too. No use
 Well thanks for your effort. And sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @ShyamK Its ok dude..! The problem is I can't come to see your screen to check what is wrong. Am sorry that i couldn't make it. I just shared what all worked for me.